# Which Ethernet cable should l use to connect two office buildings?

Tags: ethernet, lan

I am an extreme newbie in real networking. I have developed an application for our internal office management which is to be installed on 4 machines. One of the offices is in another building around 30 meters away from the main office where the server is located. In this case wireless connectivity is a no go.
We have decided to use ethernet cables for the connection. I am however unsure of the exact specification of the cable to use for the outdoor connection to the other office building since we are trying to avoid unnecessary expense. I chose the CAT5e PVC STP Cable, but l have read that there is need for grounding. Is it worth proceeding with the CAT5e PVC STP Cable on such a small network set up or there are better methods?
Moreover, is it possible for CAT5e PVC UTP Cables to fit in for the job?

Comment: Have you already done a web search for outdoor rated Ethernet cables? You might want to consult a cabling contractor also. If you want this setup to last, it will have to be done right. Otherwise weather and vermin and even humans are likely to damage the cable and cause the link to go down.

Comment: I have done some fair research which led me into choosing CAT5e PVC STP Cable. I however still feel like there could be more advice to get for better choice. Thanks.

Comment: What is the outdoor cable path? Is it buried or sitting on the ground? Or is it strung on poles or between two balconies?

Comment: You need to hire an expert. Outside Plant cabling is a specialty, and there are regulations surrounding it. For example, the outside cabling is limited by the National Electric Code on how far it can extend into the building, and you must properly ground, bond, and use lightning protection. Failure to follow the laws and regulations can get the building red-tagged (no occupation) until the problem is corrected, and in the event of a fire caused by improper installation, you may be held liable.

Comment: By the way, indoor PVC twisted-par cabling is unsuitable for outdoor use . Any moisture will change the dielectric properties and can cause failure. You are really in over your head and need professional help to install it properly and safely.

Comment: ... and I'd seriously consider (proper grade) fiber which is less susceptible to degradation (and EMI, of course).

Comment: user71659, we had decided to go with hanging it from one point to the other...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will be fine. I read your question carefully. you need 4 connections in a 4 different machines. but you don't decide on the best way and minimum cost for your project. so first of all you need a UTP Cat 6s cable roll second your need a flexible pipe. but the flexible pipe is used under the earth you are a dead open route way so then use PVC pipe. so decide your choice. I recommend you best way to install the UTP cable in an open way because in the feature your UTP cable is damaged so your team changes it easily. I hope you agree with my answer. Thanks

Comment: +1 for suggesting a pipe/open conduit, -1 for not warning about using indoor-rated cabling

Comment: Zeeshan Javed, in as much as l have understood from my little research, UTP is not really suitable for outdoor use.

Comment: Dear R kay Dear one side thing you are right but the Client ask a minimum cost for this project. So I recommend a UTP cable otherwise the best solution is a fiber cable but the fiber connection is a lot of expense. So that reason I will suggest a UTP cable.

Comment: 1.UTP CAT6 Cost
Cat6 UTP Cable Roll 1000 ft. Price $190
Distance 30 meter required 4 UTP cable connections
30*4=120 meter.  $22.8 
PVC pipe or flexible pipe 30ft $ 37
Faceplate $4
i/o and Connector $ 4
Fiber Cable Connection Cost
2. Fiber 2 Core 30 meter cost = $ 32.99
ODF price = $14.99 
Fiber patch cord =8.89*2=17.78
 2 SFP Module Price = $48.99*2 =$97.99
8 port Cisco Switch =$289
UTP patch cord 5 meter cost = $2*4=8
Faceplate I/O price also mention
Total UTP Cat6 connection Cost
Total =$257.8
And 
Fiber 2 Core cable Connection Cost
Total =460.75

Comment: 50m pre-terminated, armored OS2 duplex fiber = $60, 2x generic 1000BASE-LX SFPs = $20.